# How to include a javascript method call in onchange within an echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hi all I'm having a problem writing an echo to produce a textarea with an onchange event.

```
echo "<td class='innerTable'><div>";
echo "<textarea name='comments' id='comments' onchange="saveChanges(this,$row_model['id'])" style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:1.2em;'>";
echo "</textarea></div></td>";
```

I've tried using backslashes before the double quotes in onchange and using singlequotes but keep getting parsing errors on the textarea line. When the comment changes the saveChanges javascript should run and the ajax call should save the new comment to the database

This is my javascript method.

```
function saveChanges(object, module_id){   
    $.ajax({
        url: 'saveComments.php',
        data: 'content=' + object.value+ '&id=' + module_id,
        cache: false,
        error: function(e){
          alert(e);
        },
    success: function(response){
        // A response to say if it's updated or not
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use concatenation as follows:

```
onchange='saveChanges(this," . $row_model['id'] . ")'
```

so you echo will become

```
echo "<td class='innerTable'><div>";
echo "<textarea name='comments' id='comments' onchange='saveChanges(this," . $row_model['id'] . ")' style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:1.2em;'>";
echo "</textarea></div></td>";
```

Comment: This one was the cleanest and worked instantly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your php code to:

```
echo "<td class='innerTable'><div>";
echo <<<EOF
<textarea name='comments' id='comments' onchange="saveChanges(this,{$row_model['id']})" style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:1.2em;'>";
EOF;
echo "</textarea></div></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<td class='innerTable'><div>";
echo "<textarea name='comments' id='comments' onchange=\"saveChanges(this,$row_model['id'])\" style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:1.2em;'>";
echo "</textarea></div></td>";
```

Escape the quotes before, like in second line using "\".

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below :

```
echo "<textarea name='comments' id='comments' onchange='saveChanges(this,{$row_model["id"]});' style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:1.2em;'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You try like this

```
echo "<td class='innerTable'><div>";
echo "<textarea name='comments' id='comments' onchange='saveChanges(this,$row_model['id'])' style='font-family:sans-serif;font-size:1.2em;'>";
echo "</textarea></div></td>";
```